# How do I force strtotime() to return date instead of time when given ambiguous $time?

Tags: php, strtotime

Good evеning!

```
echo date('r', strtotime('10.01.11'));
```

Prints: *Sun, 05 Feb 2012 **10:01:11***

Expected: *Mon, 10 Jan 2011 00:00:00*

How do I force `strtotime()` to parse the input string as a date only? I have to convert a bunch of dates in different format. `DateTime::format` is not an option since I don't know all the formats the script will run into, and it's not even installed on the server (and i don't have privileges to do it).

Tried
`strtotime('day 10.01.11')`,
`strtotime('10.01.11 00:00:00')`,
`strtotime('10.01.11 midnight')`
- nothing worked.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is modifying the input an option for you?

```
$str = '10.01.11';
$str = str_replace('.', '/', $str);

echo date('r', strtotime($str));
```

However, this will still output `Sat, 01 Oct 2011 00:00:00`, according to the MM.DD.YY pattern (US standard).

---

EDIT: Depending on you usage, you might consider creating a list of regex patterns and parse the date accordingly. It is very hard to make a code like this to be open to *all* possibilities.

Comment: Got the same idea, but with `-` instead of `/` because that would automatically turn the date into US format. Unfortunately, that also didn't work: `strtotime('01-10-11')` returns _Thu, 11 Oct 2001_.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I force strtotime() to parse the input string as a date only?

You don't.  `strtotime` uses [very well-defined parsing formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).  What it generates will depend entirely on what you give it.

`'10.01.11'` is parsed as [a time format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php), as it will *always* interpret three pairs of digits separated by periods as a time.  It will recognize dates [when separated by dashes, slashes or spaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).  Annoyingly, there's an example there on the date format page that uses dots, but there doesn't seem to be a sure-fire way to *force* date parsing instead of time parsing.  Sigh, PHP.

If you need that specific format to be interpreted as a date instead of a time, you have two options.

First, you can use a different date parsing method.  If the expected format never changed, you could use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) or the horrifying [`strptime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php).  You've indicated in comments that the format will vary and your PHP version is old enough not to have DateTime, so this might not work for you.

Second, you can pre-process the data.  At least in this example, a conversion of `.` to `/` may do the trick, though `10/01/11` can be ambiguous as a date to humans.  There's nothing wrong with a little regex sniffing to determine how to best process data.

There's also a third option: if you're getting this information from users, make your application begin forcing users to enter dates in a normal, consistent, parseable format.  It may take some time to train your users to use YYYY-MM-DD, but it's probably the most sane long-term bet.

Comment: It is. The `01-10-11` is interpreted as `2001-10-11`. Regex pre-processing would be my only option I guess.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add the time set to 00:00:00 by default?
e.g.

```
echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('10.01.11'));
```

also strtotime uses the american date format so this will be translated into 1st of october 2011. it's easier to use the iso date format

Comment: I believe the `date()` function's _$format_ argument doesn't affect `strtotime()`, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Tested, this works:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.y', '10.01.11');
echo $date->format('r');
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/OH7Kyn

Comment: The OP said he doesn't want to use method where explicit format has to be specified.

Comment: 1. I don't have DateTime available and I can't install it 2. The format is not static. Please read the question carefully. But thanks anyway, your solution might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think strtotime knows how to parse those dates. To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates.

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks, but this time it really doesn't depend on me.